# SavedModel not usable in GCP / tf serving (SavedModel must exactly contain one metagraph)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

At first I wanted to use Microsoft camera trap [model](https://github.com/microsoft/CameraTraps/blob/master/megadetector.md) on GCP AI platform using the .pb SavedModel.
But it wouldn't validate the version (SavedModel must exactly contain one metagraph) so I tried with tensorflow serving (docker):

[image: docker tensorflow serving]

Checked with github/tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/saved_model_cli.py

> RuntimeError: MetaGraphDef associated with tag-set  could not be found in SavedModel

I thought the model had been simply incorrectly exported so I tried with other SavedModels like https://tfhub.dev/google/openimages_v4/ssd/mobilenet_v2/1 (downloading the tar directly to get the .pb)

But I got exactly the same errors ... (also tried with the resnet one)

Am I doing something wrong ?